# Why does getting a member expression member name differ between C# and VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, expression-trees, c#-to-vb.net

I have the following C# method:

```
private static string GetMemberName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
{
    MemberExpression memberExpr = expr.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (memberExpr == null) 
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Wrong type of lambda...");

    return memberExpr.Member.Name;
}
```

And I can use it like this to print the name of a class-level field, method param, or local var (note this is pre-C# 6.0 [`nameof` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx)):

```
private static int _myFieldVar  = 62;

private static void DoStuff(int myMethodParam)
{
    int myLocalVar = 2;
    Debug.Print(GetMemberName(() => myMethodParam)); // prints "myMethodParam"
    Debug.Print(GetMemberName(() => myLocalVar)); // prints "myLocalVar"
    Debug.Print(GetMemberName(() => _myFieldVar)); // _myFieldVariable
}
```

Now I want to convert this code to VB.NET, so here is the `GetMemberName` method:

```
Private Function GetMemberName(Of T)(expr As Expression(Of Func(Of T))) As String
    Dim memberExpr As MemberExpression = TryCast(expr.Body, MemberExpression)

    If memberExpr Is Nothing Then _
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Wrong type of lambda...")

    Return memberExpr.Member.Name
End Function
```

However, I'm noticing different results when I get the method param and local variable names, i.e. they are both prefixed with "**$VB$Local_**":

```
Private _myFieldVar As Integer = 62

Private Sub DoThis(myMethodParam As Integer)
    Dim myLocalVar = 2
    Debug.Print(GetMemberName(Function() myMethodParam)) ' prints "$VB$Local_myMethodParam""
    Debug.Print(GetMemberName(Function() myLocalVar)) ' prints "$VB$Local_myLocalVar"
    Debug.Print(GetMemberName(Function() _myFieldVar)) ' prints "_myFieldVar()" 
End Sub
```

I googled "$VB$Local_" and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083909/expressionof-funcof-t-body-member-name-bizarre-vblocal-added-if-used-in) which is very similar.  However, I think my question is different because I'm not getting this behavior with properties.  If I call this:

```
Debug.Print(GetMemberName(Function() MyProperty))
```

I get "MyProperty".  Moreover, my fundamental question is **"why is the behavior different between C# and VB.NET, i.e. what is the meaning of "$VB$Local_" and why is it absent in C#"**, whereas that post is more concerned with how to avoid that behavior in VB.NET.

Comment: But it all compiles to the same IL theoretically, so why would it be stored differently?  Why would `Member.Name` have a different value in one language vs. another?

Comment: You are simply seeing different strategies used by the C# and VB.NET compilers to name the captured variable members.  Yes, the VB.NET compiler prefixes "$VB$Local" to the variable name.  Easy to see with ildasm.exe, note the members of the _Closure__2-0 class.  This is a pure implementation detail, subject to change, that got exposed by your code.

Comment: Yes, main point would be that locals (and params) aren't members of the calling class at all, what you are looking at are the captures.

Comment: @HenkHolterman -- so I'm not looking to cast `expr.Body` to `MemberExpression`?  I can't find any info on accessing "captures" in that context...

Comment: Look at Hans's comment, your member expression refers to members of a generated class. The VB compiler is free to generate that anyway it wants.

Comment: More important: why would you ever need anything from/about a local variable? As said, that direction is full of 'implementation details'

Comment: @HenkHolterman -- I want to throw an exception if an argument is out of range or null.  I want the exception to include the name of the parameter (which constructor overloads of those exceptions take) but I don't want to "hard-code" the param names.

Comment: In C# 6 that is `nameof()`. I don't know if VB supports that in any form.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Hans Passant the 2 compilers use slightly different naming strategies for handling local variables within a Linq expression tree. Let's take a look at what both output's look like decompiled. I used ILSpy with all of the options unchecked in View => Options => decompiler tab. I also simplified the output expression tree a bit to keep the answer concise.

**C#**

```
    public static string Test()
    {
        int myLocalVar = 2;
        int myLocalVar2 = 2; // local varible never exported! note how it is not in the generated class
        myLocalVar2++;
        return GetMemberName(() => myLocalVar);
    }
```

*output*

```
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass1_0
    {
        public int myLocalVar;
    }

    public static string Test()
    {
        Class1.<>c__DisplayClass1_0 <>c__DisplayClass1_ = new Class1.<>c__DisplayClass1_0();
        <>c__DisplayClass1_.myLocalVar = 2;
        int num = 2;
        num++;
        return Class1.GetMemberName<int>(
            Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(
                Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
                    Expression.Constant(<>c__DisplayClass1_, typeof(Class1.<>c__DisplayClass1_0)),
                    typeof(Class1.<>c__DisplayClass1_0).GetMember("myLocalVar")
                )
            )
        );
    }
```

**VB**

```
Public Shared Function Test() As String
    Dim myLocalVar As Integer = 2
    Dim myLocalVar2 As Integer = 2
    myLocalVar2 = myLocalVar2 + 1
    Return GetMemberName(Function() myLocalVar)
End Function
```

*output*

```
    [CompilerGenerated]
    internal sealed class _Closure$__2-0
    {
        public int $VB$Local_myLocalVar;
    }

    public static string Test()
    {
        Class1._Closure$__2-0 closure$__2- = new Class1._Closure$__2-0();
        closure$__2-.$VB$Local_myLocalVar = 2;
        int num = 2;
        num++;
        return Class1.GetMemberName<int>(
            Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(
                Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
                    Expression.Constant(closure$__2-, typeof(Class1._Closure$__2-0)), 
                    typeof(Class1._Closure$__2-0).GetMember("$VB$Local_myLocalVar")
                )
            )
        );
    }
```

---

Both compilers create a `private sealed class` for `myLocalVar`. This is done to satisfy the requirements of the Linq expression tree. The expression tree needs to capture a reference to the local variable. The below example shows why this is needed.

```
       int localVar = 1;
       Expression<Func<int>> express = () => localVar;
       var compiledExpression = express.Compile();
       Console.WriteLine(compiledExpression());//1
       localVar++;
       Console.WriteLine(compiledExpression());//2
       Console.ReadLine();
```

---

Back to the question- why is the behavior different between C# and VB.NET, i.e. what is the meaning of "$VB$Local_" and why is it absent in C#?

The compilers generate an unbelievable amount of code for us, C# and VB.NET both do it slightly diffrently. So I am only going to answer why does VB insert `$VB$Local_`. ** To avoid name collisions.** Both C#'s DisplayClass and VB.Net's Closure is used for more than one purpose. To keep from having a collision, the name is prefixed with a key that represents the source. It just works out that C#'s key is nothing, all other language features that contribute to DisplayClass prefix with something else. Try decompiling the folowing VB.net to see why the prefix key is needed.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim myLocalVar As Integer = 2
    Dim x1 As System.Action(Of Integer) = Sub(x)
                                              System.Console.WriteLine(x)
                                              GetMemberName(Function() myLocalVar)

                                          End Sub
    x1(2)
End Sub
```

The compiled closure will be the following.

```
    [CompilerGenerated]
    internal sealed class _Closure$__2-0
    {
        public int $VB$Local_myLocalVar;

        internal void _Lambda$__0(int x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Class1.GetMemberName<int>(Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(Expression.Field(Expression.Constant(this, typeof(Class1._Closure$__2-0)), fieldof(Class1._Closure$__2-0.$VB$Local_myLocalVar)), new ParameterExpression[0]));
        }
```

async and await also use closures in this way, however they generate a lot of boilerplate code that I didn't want to paste in here.

---

**Final remarks**

Your passing in a local variable and parameter into a method named `GetMemberName`. It was only luck that under the hood the 2 compilers automatically generated types and members to satisfy linq expression trees in the first place. Fortunately the latest iteration of the compilers have the nameof operator, which is a much better way to handle this problem.